# How to create cordova plugin for the windows UWP?

Tags: ionic-framework, uwp, apache-cordova

How do we create an cordova plugin for windows uwp? I am creating an cordova app for the windows surface.In that I need to create plugin to access saml authentication through webview? Need steps to create plugin for UWP.

I have tried some of the links below to create plugin for windows, but it doesn't seems to work in uwp applications.

https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/create-plugin-windows-phone/#CreatingMethod
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/plugman.html#create-a-cordova-project
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/wp8/plugin.html#interpreting-arguments-in-c 
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/plugin.html

PS: I have followed the same links to create the iOS Plugin it works fine, but for windows it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: What error did you get when you are following the tutorials?

Comment: I am not getting any error, not able invoke the plugin fucntion which return the string, but the same when I tried with iOS its working fine? Is something missing in this tutorial for windows plugin?